# Why are Facebook Likes insisting on using the wrong product image...?

Tags: image, facebook, caching, facebook-like, scrape

My website, http://www.joaniesgifts.co.uk, includes the like button on the product pages. However, I've found that certain product pages are using the incorrect image when a user likes the page. [This page](http://www.joaniesgifts.co.uk/terramundi-money-pots/terramundi-money-pot-holiday-fund) is an example.

I think this may have been down to an original incorrect setup which is now corrected.  However, the problem remains...

The only thing I have to go on is if I use the Facebook URL linter on the above  product page I receive the following error.

> Object at URL 'http://www.joaniesgifts.co.uk/terramundi-money-pot-holiday-fund' of type '213689662010141:product' is invalid because the domain 'www.joaniesgifts.co.uk' is not allowed for the application id '213689662010141' which owns the specified object type. If you are the owner of this application, you can verify your configured 'Site Domain' at developers.facebook.com/apps/213689662010141.
>   (I have verified my site's domain)

Everything else appears fine except it is also showing the wrong image! However, under Raw Open Graph Document Information it has the correct link!

If I then click [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) - http://graph.facebook.com/10150450766583352 - it again shows the wrong image was linked!

What else could I do?

Also: The Graph API shows the incorrect image after a scrape only minutes ago.

```
{
   "url": "http://www.joaniesgifts.co.uk/terramundi-money-pot-holiday-fund",
   "type": "website",
   "title": "Terramundi Money Pot - Holiday Fund",
   "image": [
      {
         "url": "http://www.joaniesgifts.co.uk/index.php?route=product\u00252Fproduct\u00252Fcaptcha"
      }
   ],
   "updated_time": "2011-11-11T18:54:38+0000",
   "id": "10150450766583352"
}
```

Comment: There's a currently open bug about the 'product' problem - see here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/285421101492706

Comment: Thanks Igy - Great to know it wasn't just me!

Answer (score 0):

As this is an apparent bug in Facebook, I have gotten around this by removing the [Open Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Open_Graph_protocol) type: product from the Facebook meta tags. At least the page works now and links the right images!